# Build list for WPF from LINQ query result

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework-6, devexpress

What I need to learn how to construct List from query results

My DBContext:

```
public class Transport
{
    [Key]
    public int TransportID {get; set;}
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}

public class TransportOwner
{
    [Key]
    public int TransportOwnerID {get; set;}
    public int TransportID {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("TransportID")]
    public virtual Transport Transport { get; set; }
}

public virtual DbSet<Transport> Transports { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<TransportOwner> TransportOwners { get; set; }
```

In c# I created List:

```
private List<OwnerTransport> _ownerTransportList;
```

Also have a data from my DBContext:

```
var ownerTransport = DBContext.OwnerTransports.AsQueryable();

var queryResult = ownerTransport
        .Select(t => new
        {
            t.ID,
            t.PersonalCode,
            t.TransportID,
            Model = t.Transport.Model,
            Brand = t.Transport.Brand, 
        }).ToList();
```

queryResult I want to see in OwnersTransportList ant set is as ItemSource for my DataGrid

Comment: what is your problem specifically?

Comment: I don't know how to write a code in c# to create a list from my queryResult, witch I could set as a itemsource for my GridControl in WPF. I am trying this:   OwnerTransportList = savTransportList.ToList()?;

Comment: Actually don't know how to convert one list to anothet witch matches for my form

Comment: <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding OwnerTransportList}" AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" >

Comment: var ownerTransport = DBContext.OwnerTransports.ToList();

Comment: I also need to filter this list befor, because of a big amount of data ... so how to convert from querable to list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using LINQ-to-Entities to execute filters on the data in the (DB) store before pulling the data into memory through EF.

For example, to populate your WPF GridControl, execute the following code. As an example for a possible filter, I included a where clause to filter for a specific `TransportID`.

```
public ICollection<OwnerTransport> GetOwnerTransportByTransportId(int transportId, int? skip = null, int? take = null)
{
    using (var context = new DBContext())
    {
       // base query
       var query = context.OwnerTranports.AsQueryable();

       // execute filter on transport ID
       query = query.Where(t => t.TransportID == transportId.Value);

       // apply skip/take
       if (skip.HasValue)
       {
           query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
       }
       if (take.HasValue)
       {
           query = query.Take(take.Value);
       }         

       // Materialize data. This pulls it from DB store into memory.
       var data = query.ToList();

       return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how to describe List witch i want to assign to grid?

Comment: what pattern do you use to connect your model to the view? MVVM?

Comment: Acctually I am completely new in working with Oracle, Visual Studio and c# but I dear to say that WPF MVVM

Comment: I recommend you to look up information about MVVM, WPF and data binding. That way you get a basic understanding of how these techniques and patterns play together.

Comment: Ok. Thank You for Your answer